# mysql table design for self reference with time

Tags: mysql, reference, data-modeling

I need to design an address table.  The address has start and end time reflecting the life span of that address.  Because the nature of the address change such as rebuild the building, change the name etc.  User should be able to find this address's previous address name.
For example

```
    | key | address    |city   | state   | zip  |start date|end   date| ref id |
    | 1   | 1 Ark Ave  | Ytown | mystate |12345 |1990-01-01|2001-01-01| null   |
    | 2   | 10 Black Dr| Xtown | mystate |12347 |2001-01-02| null     | 1      |
```

So from "10 Black Dr." user should be able to find it previous address was "1 Ark Ave."
That means the table should have a column of reference id (ref id) to its previous address.

How to draw this relationship in EER Model?  When row 1 is deleted, what will happen to row 2?  Or row 1 cannot be deleted?

Another way is we have a reference table

```
|key | id |start date | end date   |  ref id |
|1   | 1  |1990-01-01 | 2001-01-01 |  null   |
|2   | 2  |2001-01-02 | null       |  1      |
```

and keep address table as

```
| key | address    |city   | state   | zip  |
| 1   | 1 Ark Ave  | Ytown | mystate |12345 |
| 2   | 10 Black Dr| Xtown | mystate |12347 |
```

What is the EER model looks like for second design?

Comment: How do you handle the wrong information in record #1? The one table design has a lot of issues and a better approach is to assign a location id for each address, as suggested in Randy's answer, and then log all changes (names, ...) in another table with the location id, as well a change timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

you need a concept of the location that holds a primary key

```
location
---------
location_id
optional_other_fields (latitude, longitude?)

address
----------
location_id
begin_date
end_date
street
city
postal_code 
etc.
```